# how to connect the library alglib in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, neural-network, alglib

I want to run the example from the official site [link](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#example_nn_cls2).
When I am trying to compile

```
mlptrainer trn;
multilayerperceptron network;
mlpreport rep;
real_1d_array x = "[0]";
real_1d_array y = "[0,0]";
real_2d_array xy = "[[+1,0],[+2,0],[-1,1],[-2,1],[0,0],[0,1]]";
mlpcreatetrainercls(1, 2, trn);
mlpcreatec1(1, 5, 2, network);
mlpsetdataset(trn, xy, 6);
mlptrainnetwork(trn, network, 5, rep);
```

I get an many errors they all look

> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\VK_DotaFeed\neuralnet.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to alglib::mlpcreatetrainercls(int, int, alglib::mlptrainer&)
>
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\VK_DotaFeed\neuralnet.cpp:-1: errors: undefined reference to alglib::real_1d_array::~real_1d_array()

I wrote

```
using namespace alglib;
#include "dataanalysis.h"
```

In what an error?

Comment: ***In what an error?*** Looks like you are missed adding the library to link to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the library you need for your project here;

http://www.alglib.net/download.php

Read section 4 and the first part of section 8 on the page you reference above.

Your problem is that the library has not been linked into the application.
You will have to add two lines to the PRO file of your Qt project to tell Qt where to find the library that you downloaded and the headers for the library. They will look like this;

INCLUDEPATH += /Users/sysadmin/programming/alglib/includes/????
LIBS += -L/Users/sysadmin/programming/alglib/libs  -l?????

where you will use names for your system, not mine,  and replace the ??? with the library names.

Comment: Where to get the lib? The delivery is not lib

Comment: On the page I link above look for the section Download ALGLIB Free Edition. It's below that.