# How to connect libalglib to QT project [UBUNTU]?

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I am using QT creator on my ubuntu 16.04. I need to include some library from libalglib.
I installed alglib by using this command"

```
sudo apt-get install libalglib-dev
```

After successful install I tried to include library in my project 
I added this in my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/libalglib
```

That is why now i can include alglib headers

```
#include <libalglib/specialfunctions.h>
using namespace alglib;
```

But it still write that is undifined reference:

```
main.cpp:178: undefined reference to `alglib::invchisquaredistribution(double, double)'
```

I know that I need to add something into LIBS parameter, I watched this
[how to connect the library alglib in QT C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579459/how-to-connect-the-library-alglib-in-qt-c)
but I am still do not know what i need to add.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I find the clue from the deb file.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libalglib.so
```

`LIBS += -lalglib`